# Making animated choropleth with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, animation, choropleth

I want to make an animation that shows the changes in state shape and state population every ten years. My state data is all in one large feature class. I have a polygon for each state every ten years, along with the state's population.

[image]

I want the animation to start with something like this:[image]

and end with something like this:[image] I want the animation to cycle through the different years, with maybe a 2 second pause for each year.

I know how to use graduated colors in the symbology to make the choropleth maps, I just don't know how to use the animation tools in ArcGIS Pro to make the animation.

I tried to create key frames of the map using different Definition Queries (ie CensusYear=1900), but the key frames wouldn't change. Do I need to make separate maps for each key frame? What is the best way to do this with ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Do the keyframes change when you try things other than definition queries? Are you following the steps that are outlined in these links?: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/animation/animate-the-camera.htm